# catch curl error with PHP request library

Tags: php, curl

I'm using `https://github.com/rmccue/Requests`

I'm making a request using a random Proxy sometimes the proxy will work sometimes it will fail: with different errors:
`Uncaught exception 'Requests_Exception' with message 'cURL error 28: connect() timed out!'`

 My question is: How can I catch this CURL error, and try another another proxy in a loop?

I tried `var_dump($request->status_code);` it outputs 200 reguardless of success or fail.

```
include('../library/Requests.php');

// Next, make sure Requests can load internal classes
Requests::register_autoloader();

// Now let's make a request via a proxy.
$options = array(
    'proxy' => '$randomProxyIP:$randomProxyPort')
);
$request = Requests::get('http://httpbin.org/ip', array(), $options );


var_dump($request->status_code);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
    $request = Requests::get('http://httpbin.org/ip', array(), $options );
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In [documentation](http://requests.ryanmccue.info/api/) you can find lots of exceptions. Also your message means that you have exception `Requests_Exception` to catch. All of them are subclases from `Requests_Exception` ([here](http://requests.ryanmccue.info/api/class-Requests_Exception.html)) so in basics way you should:

```
try {
    $request = Requests::get('http://httpbin.org/ip', array(), $options );
} catch (Requests_Exception $e) {
    //something goes wrong
}
```